# About reading the contents of file in qt

Tags: c++, qt

```
gdsddsf
Fri Feb 6 2015
A+
231
342
3232
3fsdfdsa
1242141241
242112

fdsasds
Fri Feb 6 2015
A+
213
213
12312
4321
4321421234
```

these are the two entries in my database.
I want to print them in table view using qt.
I can read the contents of file but i cant understand how to go to the next table entry after the end of the first 8 lines.
Just tell me how to go to the next entry after 8 readlines

```
 void MainWindow::on_search_clicked()
{
     QString name,dob,height,weight,bloodgrp,policy,add,contact;
    QString filename = "/home/pushkar/Person/database.txt";
        QFile file(filename);
        if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
        {
        QTextStream in(&file);

        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code shows you how do something after 8 lines of a file is read.

```
QFile file("c:/Qt/in.txt");
int line_count=0;
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly); //| QIODevice::Text)
QString line[amountOfLinesInFile];
QTextStream in(&file);
while( !in.atEnd())
{
    line[line_count]=in.readLine();
    line_count++;

    if(lineCount % 8)
    {
        // Do Something
    }
}
```